# Should backup necessary before upgrade from ESXi 4.1 to ESXi 5.1?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

We are using ESXi 4.1 and we need to move to ESXi 5 as we need VMs for Windows server 2012 and Windows 8.

Our servers are already having VMs. So we want to upgrade without reinstall.

Some people advised to have backup before initiating the process.

But we don't have that much hard disk capacity to backup some where.

Would Upgrade to latest ESXi affect existing VMs? Whether backup is must or it is better to have? [If it is must we must think some other solution]

Comment: You should *always* ensure you have backups before making any significant change to *any* system. Why do you image this might be an exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Necessary' - not so much, but it is advisable certainly, though you should be backing things up anyway to be honest. Obviously the upgrade *shouldn't* be an issue but 5.1 is VERY new, in fact do you really want to be using it so soon in a production environment?

Comment: whether Previous version of ESXi would support windows server 2012 and windows 8 preview?

Comment: They're both supported by 'ESXi 5.0 U1 Tech Preview' but you seem to be in an awful rush to get the latest and greatest, is there a feature you NEED? in professional system administration we tend to run code that's supported and stable, W8 isn't out yet.

Comment: Some how my manager rushed me . I also blindly followed it. thanks for your advice.I will tell him to arrange a sandbox or server where less number of VM available.

Comment: Yes, always test before going into production, every week we have someone come to ServerFault with their tales of lost data and broken businesses because they weren't professional about running their IT, don't be that guy ok.

Answer (score 1):

Before upgrading anything it is a good idea to do backups of what you are upgrading since there is always a chance that something might go wrong.